# Getting dropbox access_token works on windows but not on windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, oauth, token, dropbox

I have a strange problem when requesting access_token from dropbox. 
The same code works perfectly on windows. I get request token, open web page and then get access token.

On windows phone the same exact sequence does not work. After getting back request token I can open web page and login but then oauth\access_token fails every time with the following

> WebException:
>   Message="The remote server returned an error: NotFound.
>   StatusCode=System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Forbidden
>   StatusDescription=Forbidden

Just for fun I tried debugging both windows phone and windows code side by side and swapping request token key and token secret between two. I found out that logging into dropbox on windows phone was the root of the problem. I could never get access token if login was done from the browser on the phone but it worked fine on desktop. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: by windows do you mean windows phone emulator?

Comment: windows == windows, windows phone == windows phone emulator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution was very simple. Just before opening dropbox page I added one line:

> myBrowserControl.IsScriptEnabled = true;

At first I used web browser control on my app page and only set URL for dropbox login. All other settings of that control were default which meant that by default scripting was disabled on that control. Dropbox requires javascript to log in so without scripting enabled login page just did not work.